# How to enable lsp-ui-sideline in doom emacs?

Tags: emacs

In my doom emacs `config.el` file I set `lsp-ui-sideline` like so:

```
(setq lsp-ui-sideline t)
```

Then I closed, ran `doom sync` and reopened emacs. I'm not seeing any pops like show in the [documentation](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui#lsp-ui-sideline). Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong. FYI this is primarily for typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the variable you want to set is `lsp-ui-sideline-enable` The documentation for it reads:

```
Whether or not to enable ‘lsp-ui-sideline’.
```

Comment: Good find, but still not showing up for some reason.

Comment: hmm strange, a few things to try: does `Lsp-Ui` show up when you `C-h m`? Have you set `lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover`, `lsp-ui-sideline-show-diagnostics` and so on? Do other lsp features work?  Is it just typescript the sideline is not appearing in, or is it all languages?